# UIImage from UIView if UIView is outside window bounds

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiimage

I have UIScrollView with many UIView views added to the content. I would like to convert UIView and its subviews to UIImage and I know how to do it if the UIView is currently visible on the device screen. Is it possible to convert UIView (subview in UIScrollView) into UIImage if UIView is not in UIScrollView visible rect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you just iterate over all subviews taking a screenshot of each UIView inside the UIScrollView ?

The following class may help with taking screenshots:
http://ioscodesnippet.com/2011/08/25/rendering-any-uiviews-into-uiimage-in-one-line/

Hope you find a solution.

Thanks,
Michael

Comment: Shouldn't UIView be visible on the device screen to take a screenshot?

Comment: I've checked about snippet and it works! Thanks a lot. I'll accept your answer when available.